# Azure Worker Role data volatility

Tags: azure

I would like to create an application that holds large amount of volatile data in memory. Only small part of this data needs to be persisted when host machine shuts down, or in case of maintenance. Outages should be rare, this in memory data needs to be accessible for most of the time, but rare restrats of service is bearable.

If I have been developing for a server, I would create a WindowsService, which runs reliably while the machine is up, and I would persist a fraction of the data in the OnStop() method.

I'm thinking of moving this whole thing to the cloud. The question is that if a Worker Role is similiar to a Windows Service from this point of view? Does it run most of the time with rare outages, or is it recycled / restarted from time to time or when it is idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Windows Service, Worker role is meant for processing background tasks. However one thing you would need to keep in mind that your worker role can go down any time. It may be because of hardware failure or software updates. Thus you can't always assume this to be highly available. That's why Windows Azure recommends deploying multiple instances of your application.

What you could do is have multiple instances of your worker role running and all of them sharing a common cache where you would put volatile data. Do take a look at Windows Azure Caching (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx) where you could either dedicate some memory of a VM (i.e. an instance) for caching purpose or have a full VM dedicated for caching. That way you'll have your volatile data somewhere outside of your worker roles and thus making it available to all instances.